# Python ctypes datatypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to write a python program that interfaces with a scada software program. The scada program provides an api through some dll files and provides some example code (written in C I think) in the help. So basically I am trying to translate the example code into python. This is the code I am working with:

```
HANDLE     hSearch;
HANDLE     hObject;
HANDLE     hFind;
// Search the Tag table
hSearch = ctFindFirst(hCTAPI, "Tag", NULL, &amp;hObject, 0);
if (hSearch == NULL) {
    // no tags found
} else {
    do {
        char    sName[32];
        // Get the tag name
        ctGetProperty(hObject, "Tag", sName, sizeof(sName), NULL,
        DBTYPE_STR);
    } while (ctFindNext(hSearch, &amp;hObject));
    ctFindClose(hSearch);
    }
// Get Historical Trend data via CTAPI
// Get 100 samples of the CPU trend at 2 second
hFind = ctFindFirst(hCTAPI, "CTAPITrend(\"10:15:00 \", \"11/8/1998\", 2,              100, 0, \"CPU\")", &amp;hObject, 0);
while (hFind) {
    char    sTime[32], sDate[32], sValue[32];
    ctGetProperty(hObject, "TIME", sTime, sizeof(sTime), NULL, DBTYPE_STR);
    ctGetProperty(hObject, "DATE", sDate, sizeof(sDate), NULL, DBTYPE_STR);
    ctGetProperty(hObject, "CPU", sValue, sizeof(sValue), NULL, DBTYPE_STR);
    // do something with the trend data.
    if (!ctFindNext(hFind, &amp;hObject)) {
        ctFindClose(hFind);
        hFind = NULL;
        break;
    }
}
```

I am having two problems. The first is I don't know how to use the `DBTYPE_STR` datatype in the `ctGetProperty` function using ctypes. The API help provides this information on that parameter (dwType):

```
dwType
Type: DWORD 
Input/output: Input 
Description: The desired return type as follows: 

Value        | Meaning  
DBTYPE_UI1   | UCHAR  
DBTYPE _I1   | 1 byte INT  
DBTYPE _I2   | 2 byte INT  
DBTYPE _I4   | 4 byte INT  
DBTYPE _R4   | 4 byte REAL  
DBTYPE _R8   | 8 byte REAL  
DBTYPE _BOOL | BOOLEAN  
DBTYPE_BYTES | Byte stream  
DBTYPE _STR  | NULL Terminated STRING
```

The other thing I can't figure out is how to declare a handle datatype using ctypes.
Any help you guys could provide is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the module "ctypes.wintypes".  It defines a lot of Windows types.  It has "HANDLE" and "DWORD" defined for you.

dwType is a DWORD, so it is expecting an unsigned 32-bit integer.  It looks like it is a constant value.  If you can find the include file used for C/C++ you can probably find out what integer DBTYPE_STR evaluates to, and just define the same value in Python.